# Socket.io client: Getting error "io is not defined" or "#<Object> has no method 'connect'"

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, client-side

Ok so I'm basically having the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603224/node-server-socket-io-io-is-not-defined). But the answers given there don't work for me. So let me re-explain my problem. First of all, here's my code:

**Server-Side Javascript (app.js)**

```
var io = require('socket.io');
...
var sio = io.listen(app);
```

**Client-Side Javascript (client.js)**

```
3: var socket = (s)io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
//the (s) represents testing with and without the s out of desperateness :)
```

**Client-Side Template (Jade)**

```
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
script(src='/javascripts/client.js')
```

So from what I've read it seems like socket.io should be handling putting the socket.io.js file there but I'm guessing that I have something configured wrong because it's not doing that. Anyways the errors I get with this are:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined - client.js line 3
```

After doing some research it seemed that I could change the jade file to link directly to a stable file. So by changing my code to this:

**Client-Side Template (Jade)**

```
script(src='http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js')
script(src='/javascripts/client.js')
```

Then the error that I get from this is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connect' - client.js line 3
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now. And it seems that I need to have socket.io-client so I made sure that it is installed. I dunno if this will but I am using Express.js as well and I will give you the layout of my files. 

**/project**

```
app.js  /node_modules  package.json  /public  /routes  /views
```

**/project/node_modules**

```
/connect  /express  /jade  /jquery  /socket.io  /stylus
```

**/project/node_modules/socket.io**

```
/benchmarks  index.js  Makefile       package.json  restrict_jsonp.patch
History.md   /lib      /node_modules  Readme.md
```

**/project/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules**

```
/policyfile  /redis  /socket.io-client
```

**/project/public**

```
/images  /javascripts  /jquery  /stylesheets
```

**/project/public/javascripts**

```
client.js
```

Anyways, any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: What version of Express are you using? If 3.0, see if [socket.io.js not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191048/socket-io-js-not-found/10192084#10192084) is of any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Felix Loether pointed out, the API for Express changed from 2.* to 3.* After spending way too many hours trying to figure out the best way to re-work my code I decided to re-install express to an earlier version by doing this:

```
npm install express@2.5.8 -g
```

There is a lot more support (as of today) for Express 2.* so as I am still learning it's better for me to use the earlier version.

Comment: After searching for quite a while this ended up being the best solution.  I had to run sudo npm install a second time to get node to use the older version of express.