# Javascript scopes and function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, use-effect

I know how functions are closure in Javascript and how they can access variables declared in their parent scope. Here I have defined a variable named socket in a functional component

```
function someName() {
    const ENDPOINT = "localhost:5000";
    let socket

    useEffect(() => {
          socket = io(ENDPOINT)
      // and some code
    }, [])

   const handleClick = () => {
         socket.emit('someEvent', someMessage)  // error: cannot read property emit of undefined
         }
   }

   return (
        <input />
        <button onClick={handleClick}
         )
```

when the component mounts, useEffect is called and defines the socket variable and when the function runs
the variable is already defined.
why am I getting that error on the handleClick function?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with your use of `useEeffect`. Are you sure you are using `io(ENDPOINT)` correctly? You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603224/node-server-socket-io-io-is-not-defined).

Comment: @nibble  Unfortunately it is wrong.  socket will be undefined here.

Comment: You will want to use a ref to store your socket id.

Comment: What does `io` returns?

Comment: @Yousaf  It's socket.io, as mentioned in his tags.   https://socket.io/

Comment: @Keith no worries. I removed my comment after thinking a little more about it.

Comment: Missing protocol for the endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that on next render (after the on mount callback), `socket` value is redefined and its value is `undefined`.

Possible fix should like like so:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import io from "socket.io";

const ENDPOINT = "...";
let socket = io(ENDPOINT);

function Component() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    socket.emit("someEvent", "some message");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input />
      <button onClick={handleClick} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Notice that `socket.io` should have a single instance (global variable/singleton), such instance should exposed in other file (export it), then every component should use it independently by improting the instance.

Comment: Why does defining the variables outside of the component help? What happens if multiple `Component`s are rendered on a page? (These are not meant to be challenges... they're just questions)

Comment: You should have a single instance of `socket.io`, such instance should exposed in other file (export it), then every component should `import` it and use independently.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444154/why-need-useref-to-contain-mutable-variable-but-not-define-variable-outside-the/57444430#57444430 for differences between `useRef` and outer scope variables.

Comment: There is no hard fast rule here, there is nothing wrong in using useEffect for mounting a socket.io connection.    In some ways it may even have benefits,.  eg.  In a SPA there maybe only a few pages that require socket.io connection, so having it as a component could save resources at both client & server.  After all a socket.io connection that does nothing still takes resources.

Comment: How it has to do with what I said? You can close connection on unmount, still you have a single instance

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` runs every time its dependencies change. In your case, the dependency is `[]`, meaning it will never change, this the useEffect will never run more than once.

Therefore, every time your component re-renders, a new `socket` variable is created, and because the `useEffect` is never run again, the variable stays `undefined`.

What you need to do is to make sure the same `socket` is returned on every re-render. The easiest and the recommended way to do it is to use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). The `useRef` hook ensures that the same reference to a value is returned on every re-render.

You code should look something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import io from 'something';

function someName() {
  const ENDPOINT = "localhost:5000";
  const socket = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io(ENDPOINT);
    // and some code
  }, [])

  const handleClick = () => {
    socket.current.emit('someEvent', someMessage);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input />
      <button onClick={handleClick}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could `socket.current` be `undefined` when the button is clicked?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, definitely, but the case will not happen for a real human using the application because the `useEffect` will run relatively immediately after the page is rendered.

Comment: The socket could fail?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted, if this is the correct place to do socket init is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @evolutionxbox should I babysit the OP through all these problems?

Comment: @yqlim nope. I’m asking these questions. The downvote wasn’t mine either.