# Local node.js server connect to http website

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, websocket

I currently own a website, which will be used for global access and a database. I am also  building devices that run a local node.js server, that forms a connection to this website.

So I guess this would be a reverse websocket? I don't own the webserver, it's hosted, so I'd assume I would use php.

I'm needing a 2 way connection that can push or request updates from both ends... Maybe websockets isn't the answer in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9688972/3556874 .. this might be what you are looking for

Comment: Hmmmmm is this server-server? Since I don't own the webserver, I can't run node.js on that end :(