# Get HTML page to communicate with node-xmpp/xmpp server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-xmpp

Please keep in mind that I am VERY new to all of this javascript/node.js style of HTML coding. In the past, all I have ever done with HTML is static/information style pages.

I am trying to create an HTML webpage that will take xmpp related information from a user (server address, port, user JID, password, chat messages, other user JID, etc.) and route it through the node.js server to the xmpp server. Ultimately, what I am trying to do is take the [webrtc.io code](https://github.com/webRTC/) and extend it to be tied to and interact with users on an XMPP server. In trying to do this, I found the node-xmpp module and "installed" it (npm install) to the node_modules folder within my project working directory.

I then created a very basic index.html file (text input boxes) that takes user information and then calls functions within a javascript file that is included in the index.html file. Within the javascript file, I added the require function/call `const xmpp = require('node-xmpp')`, added the `var client = new xmpp.Client({[connection settings]});` and then started with some basic stanza handler and other xmpp functions.

When I then "run" the code in the browser, before I even start entering in information, I see that the console is reporting errors. At first they were errors with the xmpp functions I wrote, so I commented everything out to just have the `new xmpp.Client({})` line just to see if it would even connect. But then, I would get an error with the `cont xmpp = require('node-xmpp')`. That error is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined (anonymous function)

From my limited understanding of all of this html/javascript/server stuff, I think what is happening is that the client/browser does not know/have access to either the node.js or node-xmpp library.

Is this right? Should I be doing things differently? And are there any good tutorials/documentation out there that covers this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're saying, you're trying to execute the node code within the browser. Node source should be executed on the server, not in the browser. You'll have two sets of JavaScript files: Those you serve to the browser to be executed on the browser and those that are executed on the server using a node instance.  If I misunderstood, please tell us a little bit more about the structure of your system.

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to follow your advice and thus I am abandoning my attempts to have the browser/client try and manage the xmpp stuff, and instead just have the server manage all of the connections.

Comment: the best way of handeling XMPP connections using a browser would be to have a client controlling a connection to the XMPP server (for example chat.facebook.com) via a BOSH server, this would also save more bandwidth instead of having to constantly send/receive data from your server for every incoming/outgoing message

Answer (score 0):

the require() function is unknown caused the problem. I think you may have made some mistakes including node.js.

Check this [`require 'socket.io-client.js'` not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785979/socket-io-client-issues-require-socket-io-client-js-not-working)

You may find the answer to your question.