# How can I connect a node.js server page to my sockets server as though it were a client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, passport.socketio

I've seen many similar questions here, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785979/require-socket-io-client-js-not-working) about connecting servers to sockets, however, that doesn't seem to be working.

My goal is to have one of my server pages occasionally emit an "advance" event to all of the connected clients. My sockets server listener (sockets.js) looks like this

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('advance', function () {
        console.log('advancing clients');
        io.emit('advance');
    });
});
```

and my other server page (queue.js) has this code

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client');
socket.connect('localhost:5000');
socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('advance');
});
```

I have also tried

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client');
socket.connect('localhost:5000');
socket.emit('advance');
```

Both of those were in the other question I linked, however both of those failed. In the case of the first example, I received the error

```
socket.on is not a function
```

and on the second

```
socket.emit is not a function
```

it would seem that socket.connect worked, however, socket.on and socket.emit both failed. The idea is that queue.js will emit an event to all the clients, so they know to request the next song from the server.

As bonus points, I happen to be using [passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) to authenticate my users (though I don't seem to be getting the "ioAuthFail" message that would normally occur when a user attempts to connect and is not authenticated).

for what it's worth, my socket authentication code looks like

```
io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
    //cookieParser:
    key:'user',
    secret:'secret',
    store:new MongoStore({mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection}),
    success:onAuthorizeSuccess,
    fail:function(){console.log('ioAuthFail')}
}));
```

If there's a better way to advance the clients than using socket.io, i would also accept that, but for now it seems like this is the best way for me, assuming I can get this working.

**EDIT**
as mentioned through comments, changing my code to

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
socket = io.connect('localhost:5000');
socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('advance');
});
socket.emit('advance');
```

doesn't *break* it, but it doesn't *work*, either.

Comment: Try `var io = require('socket.io-client'); var socket = io.connect(); socket.on(…`

Comment: i change my code to
`socket = io.connect('localhost:5000');`

`socket.on('connect', function () {`

`socket.emit('advance');`

`});`

`socket.emit('advance');`

That doesn't seem to break it, but i'm not recieving any console.log from my socket server