# Howto use underscore.loop

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

For a web-app I'm building, I'm really interested in recursing through an object tree and modifying nodes on the fly. There's an [underscore mixin](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/wiki/Mixin-Catalog) that promises that, [underscore.loop](https://github.com/benekastah/underscore.loop), but I can't seem to pull it into my page. I get a script error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'mixin' of undefined

which is on [line 33 of the tool](https://github.com/benekastah/underscore.loop/blob/master/dist/underscore.loop.js#L33).

Now, `underscore.loop.js` is pulled in after `backbone.js` and `underscore-data.js`.

1. Both of these tools use Underscore, and
2. Underscore is definitely available after trying `underscore.loop`.

So why can't `underscore.loop.js` see Underscore. It uses pretty much the same scoping and initialization semantics as `underscore-data.js`. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look a little higher in the source for underscore.loop and [you'll see this](https://github.com/benekastah/underscore.loop/blob/master/dist/underscore.loop.js#L8):

```
var RecursiveCall, flatStackLoop, _;
var __slice = Array.prototype.slice;
try {
  _ = require('underscore');
} catch (_e) {}
```

Note the `var ... _;` and how `_` is initialized. So `underscore.loop.js` is trying to make sure that `underscore.js` is loaded and that it has a local version of `_` to use. [`require` is a node.js-ism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168451/javascript-require-on-client-side) so you don't have it in your client-side world and that leaves you with an undefined value in `_`. You can either grab a [client-side library that supplies a node.js compatible require](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5168482/479863):

- [require.js](http://requirejs.org)
- [head.js](http://headjs.com)
- [Lab.js](http://labjs.com)
- ...

or edit your copy of `underscore.loop.js` to not include the `var _;` declaration or the `try` block. Alternatively, you could hack up a little `require` implementation of your own that just does this:

```
function require(what) {
    return what == 'underscore' ? window._ : null;
}
```

or even:

```
function require(ignored) { return window._ }
```

and load your `require` hack between `underscore.js` and `underscore.loop.js`.

Comment: Ho haa, that did the trick. Thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to use the darn thing :) I mostly want to traverse the tree (like in a visitor pattern), find and update nodes on the fly.

Comment: I'm the author of underscore.loop. For any who care to know, I pushed a change that fixes this issue. Should work on its own now.

Comment: @benekastah: That's awesome! I love it when people (such as [apneadiving](http://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving) and gmaps4rails)use SO as a support forum for their software.

Comment: @muistooshort Agreed! This is the best support forum there is. Why use anything else?

Comment: @benekastah I added an underscore.loop.js tag if you want to note the bug fix as an answers for posterity.