# how to communicate between two node.js instances, one client one server

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner in node.js (infact started just today). One of the basic concepts is not clear to me, which I am asking here & couldn't find on SO.

Reading some tutorials on the web I wrote a client side & a server side code:

***Server side (say server.js)***:

```
var http = require('http'); //require the 'http' module

//create a server
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  //function called when request is received
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  //send this response
  response.end('Hello World\nMy first node.js app\n\n -Gopi Ramena');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

***Client side (say client.js)***:

```
var http=require('http');

//make the request object
var request=http.request({
  'host': 'localhost',
  'port': 80,
  'path': '/',
  'method': 'GET'
});

//assign callbacks
request.on('response', function(response) {
   console.log('Response status code:'+response.statusCode);

   response.on('data', function(data) {
     console.log('Body: '+data);
   });
});
```

**Now**, to run the server, I type `node server.js` in the terminal or cmd prompt. & it runs successfully logs the message in the console & also outputs the response when I browse to 127.0.0.1:1337.

**But**, how to I run client.js? I could not understand how to run the client side code.

Comment: Node is server side not client side. Take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168451/javascript-require-on-client-side

Comment: Not sure where you found client.js or what you expect it to do, but that is not something you could put in a browser.  If by client, you mean another Node.js application, sure.  I think the tutorial you found was instructing you on how to write a server that accesses HTTP resources on other servers.

Comment: Where did you find that `client.js`? Did you write it yourself? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: so how does the client communicate with the node.js server. I mean the server cant just keep on outputing values at specified time or based on specified urls.

Comment: @jsalonen http://www.slideshare.net/Sudar/introduction-to-nodejs-13354652

Comment: Judging from the slides, he is just pointing out that you can use node.js either as a client or as a server. You don't need to use node.js in both roles if you don't want to - and in fact, if you want to implement web applications, you should use node.js only as a server.

Comment: The title was very misleading.

Comment: It is good question and it is documented in the NodeJS version 11.8.0 [Client Example](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_client_side_example) and in [http.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest); but it is more easy to use [XHR module](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=xmlhttprequest) or [AXIOS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) that can be used isomorphically in browser and server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: you can use the command

```
node client.js
```

to run your "client side" code, it will send one http request

Regarding to what's `server side` and what's `client side`, it's really depends on the context.

Although in most cases, `client side` means the code running on your browser or your mobile phone app, `server side` means the "server" or "back end" your browser or your mobile phone is talking to.

In your case, I think it's more like one "server" talks to another "server", and they are both on the back end, since that's what node.js is designed for

Comment: @gopi1410 as Larry said, if you want your client.js talks to your server.js, you should change the port of your client.js to 1337

Comment: yup I changed 'host' to '127.0.0.1' and 'port' to 1337, but still when I run `node client.js`, it doesn't show any error, but also it doesnot output anything in the console. Shouldn't is show the response status code??

Comment: @gopi1410 you need to add `request.end();` in the end