# Relation between CommonJS, AMD and RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs, amd, commonjs

I'm still very confused about **CommonJS, AMD** and **RequireJS**, even after reading a lot.

I know that **CommonJS** (formerly **ServerJS**) is a group for defining some **JavaScript** specifications (i.e. modules) when the language is used outside the browser. **CommonJS** modules specification has some implementation like **Node.js** or **RingoJS**, right?

> What's the relation between **CommonJS**, **Asynchronous Module Definition** (AMD) and **RequireJS**?
>
> Is **RequireJS** an implementation of the **CommonJS** module definition? If yes, what's **AMD** then?

Comment: Reading http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html would clarify a lot as it mentions all them. (posting it as a comment as I don't consider this a full answer).

Comment: Can I ask or add more; How or where does the ES2015 import statements fit into all of these; e.g. import Ember from 'ember';

Answer (score 813, accepted):

**RequireJS** implements the **AMD** API [(source)](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html).

**CommonJS** is a way of defining modules with the help of an `exports` object, that defines the module contents. Simply put, a CommonJS implementation might work like this:

```
// someModule.js
exports.doSomething = function() { return "foo"; };

//otherModule.js
var someModule = require('someModule'); // in the vein of node    
exports.doSomethingElse = function() { return someModule.doSomething() + "bar"; };
```

Basically, CommonJS specifies that you need to have a `require()` function to fetch dependencies, an `exports` variable to export module contents and a module identifier (which describes the location of the module in question in relation to this module) that is used to require the dependencies ([source](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1.1)). CommonJS has various implementations, including **Node.js**, which you mentioned.

CommonJS was not particularly designed with browsers in mind, so it doesn't fit in the browser environment very well (*I really have no source for this--it just says so everywhere, including [the RequireJS site.*](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html)) Apparently, this has something to do with asynchronous loading, etc.

On the other hand, RequireJS implements AMD, which is designed to suit the browser environment ([source](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)). Apparently, AMD started as a spinoff of the CommonJS Transport format and evolved into its own module definition API. Hence the similarities between the two. The new feature in AMD is the `define()` function that allows the module to declare its dependencies before being loaded. For example, the definition could be:

```
define('module/id/string', ['module', 'dependency', 'array'], 
function(module, factory function) {
  return ModuleContents;  
});
```

So, CommonJS and AMD are **JavaScript** module definition APIs that have different implementations, but both come from the same origins.

- **AMD** is more suited for the browser, because it supports asynchronous loading of module dependencies.
- **RequireJS** is an implementation of **AMD**, while at the same time trying to keep the spirit of **CommonJS** (mainly in the module identifiers).

To confuse you even more, RequireJS, while being an AMD implementation, offers a CommonJS wrapper so CommonJS modules can almost directly be imported for use with RequireJS.

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
  var someModule = require('someModule'); // in the vein of node    
  exports.doSomethingElse = function() { return someModule.doSomething() + "bar"; };
});
```

Comment: Check out http://uRequire.org project that bridges the gaps of the 2 formats - write in either (or both), deploy to any of the two or simple <script>

Comment: So…, if requirejs can load commonjs modules, than it shouldn't be a problem to load node modules (since they're using commonjs's approach) right? If my first statement is true - is it possible to load requirejs modules to node module then?

Comment: @orustammanapov The CommmonJS files will lack the `define(...)` wrapper in the last example in this answer.  A server-side JS preprocessor could add this wrapper (it would just be textual JS before and after the existing CommonJS definition.)

Comment: FYI [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) will now let you use CommonJS in the browser.

Comment: @Eruant But, it is still has not that asynchronously nature as AMD.

Comment: [Writing modular js](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/), Write up by addyosmani which also has a sub section discussing on whether CommonJS is suitable for browser or not.

Comment: The reason why CommonJS doesn't fit in the browser as mentioned in RequireJS docs - *"The CommonJS require() is a synchronous call, it is expected to return the module immediately. This does not work well in the browser"*. More info [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html).

Comment: @deeperx - Isn't that irrelevant since it's concatenating the files so the server only has to serve a single one?

Comment: @aaaaaa you might want to enable some features depending on the user request; so AMD's async nature may come handy.

Comment: Can I ask or add more; How or where does the ES2015 import statements fit into all of these; e.g. import Ember from 'ember';

Answer (score 212):

[CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) is more than that - it's a project to define a common API and ecosystem for JavaScript. One part of CommonJS is the [Module](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) specification. Node.js and RingoJS are server-side JavaScript runtimes, and yes, both of them implement modules based on the CommonJS Module spec.

[AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md) (Asynchronous Module Definition) is another specification for modules. [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) is probably the most popular implementation of AMD. One major difference from CommonJS is that AMD specifies that modules are loaded *asynchronously* - that means modules are loaded in parallel, as opposed to blocking the execution by waiting for a load to finish.

AMD is generally more used in client-side (in-browser) JavaScript development due to this, and CommonJS Modules are generally used server-side. However, you can use either module spec in either environment - for example, RequireJS offers [directions for running in Node.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/) is a CommonJS Module implementation that can run in the browser.

Comment: Why is the CommonJS homepage so horrible... I'm just trying to view the offical spec. It has syntax errors, incomplete documentation and the wiki page isn't resolving.

Comment: That's not what it means to load modules asynchronously. You might be talking about dynamic/lazy loading. With async, you suggest a file to load and then some time later it will call back when it has finished loading. With sync, you suggest a file to load and then the whole thread blocks until that file has finished loading; no further code executes until the file loads. The former can yield better performance at the cost of unpredictability, while the latter can yield the same results every time and is thus more predictable. Do note these quirks can be mitigated using various optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now that modules are official in JS with ES2015, does this mean that they are preffered more than AMD or common JS?

Comment: It does not mean that they are preferred. It's all up to developer needs. I don't think that leaving no option and going for ES6 modules is especially good idea. Using good UMD however, you can combat that issue. Loading CommonJS bundles synced with AMD is a good (best) idea in general (for performance sake improvements). If you feel like you should have more control, obviously. And you should.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Your wording is more precise and concise.

Answer (score 201):

## The short answer would be:

**[CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules)** and **[AMD](https://github.com/amdjs)** are specifications (or formats) on how modules and their dependencies should be declared in javascript applications.

**[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)** is a script loader library that is AMD compliant, [curljs](http://davidwalsh.name/curljs) being another example.

### CommonJS compliant:

Taken from [Addy Osmani's book](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailcommonjs).

```
// package/lib is a dependency we require
var lib = require( "package/lib" );

// behavior for our module
function foo(){
    lib.log( "hello world!" );
}

// export (expose) foo to other modules as foobar
exports.foobar = foo;
```

### AMD compliant:

```
// package/lib is a dependency we require
define(["package/lib"], function (lib) {

    // behavior for our module
    function foo() {
        lib.log( "hello world!" );
    }

    // export (expose) foo to other modules as foobar
    return {
        foobar: foo
    }
});
```

Somewhere else the module can be used with:

```
require(["package/myModule"], function(myModule) {
    myModule.foobar();
});
```

## Some background:

Actually, [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS) is much more than an API declaration and only a part of it deals with that. AMD started as a draft specification for the module format on the CommonJS list, but full consensus wasn't reached and further development of the format moved to the [amdjs group](https://github.com/amdjs). Arguments around which format is better state that CommonJS attempts to cover a broader set of concerns and that it's better suited for server side development given its synchronous nature, and that AMD is better suited for client side (browser) development given its asynchronous nature and the fact that it has its roots in Dojo's module declaration implementation.

### Sources:

- [RequireJS - Why AMD?](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)
- [Addy Osmani - Learning JavaScript Design Patterns - Modern Modular JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modularjavascript)

Comment: Seeing code rather than descriptions helps! :) `AMD compliant` is actually RequireJS, right?

Comment: Am I missing something, or is there something mistyped? You define "package/lib" but then require "package/myModule".

Comment: I always like to read a bit about the history of why something's the way it is! Thanks for providing that background!

Comment: @RullDawg No, “package/lib” is not defined here, it is a 3rd party dependency _used_ here.

Answer (score 30):

[Quoting](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/)

**AMD**:

- One browser-first approach
- Opting for asynchronous behavior and simplified backwards compatibility
- It doesn't have any concept of File I/O.
- It supports objects, functions, constructors, strings, JSON and many other types of modules.

**CommonJS**:

- One server-first approach
- Assuming synchronous behavior
- Cover a broader set of concerns such as I/O, File system, Promises and more.
- Supports unwrapped modules, it can feel a little more close to the [ES.next/Harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules) specifications, freeing you of the define() wrapper that `AMD` enforces.
- Only support objects as modules.

Answer (score 19):

It is quite normal to organize JavaScript program modular into several files and to call `child-modules` from the `main js module`.

The thing is JavaScript doesn't provide this. Not even today in latest browser versions of Chrome and FF.

> But, is there any keyword in JavaScript to call another JavaScript module?

This question may be a total collapse of the world for many because the answer is **No**.

---

In ES5 ( released in 2009 ) JavaScript had no keywords like **import**, **include**, or **require**.

ES6 saves the day ( released in 2015 ) proposing the **import** keyword (  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import ), and now all [modern browsers support](https://caniuse.com/es6-module-dynamic-import) this.

If you use Babel 6.18.0 and transpile with ES2015 option only

```
import myDefault from "my-module";
```

you will get `require` again.

```
"use strict";
var _myModule = require("my-module");
var _myModule2 = _interopRequireDefault(_myModule);
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

This is because `require` means the module will be loaded from Node.js. Node.js will handle everything from system level file read to wrapping functions into the module.

Because in JavaScript functions are the only wrappers to represent the modules.

> I'm a lot confused about CommonJS and AMD?

Both CommonJS and AMD are just two different techniques how to overcome the JavaScript "defect" to load modules smart.

Answer (score 2):

**AMD**

- introduced in JavaScript to scale JavaScript project into multiple files
- mostly used in browser based application and libraries
- popular implementation is [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html), [Dojo Toolkit](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/index.html)

**CommonJS**:

- it is specification to handle large number of functions, files and modules of big project
- initial name ServerJS introduced in January, 2009 by Mozilla
- renamed in August, 2009 to CommonJS to show the broader applicability of the APIs
- initially implementation were server, nodejs, desktop based libraries

Example

upper.js file

```
exports.uppercase = str => str.toUpperCase()
```

main.js file

```
const uppercaseModule = require('uppercase.js')
uppercaseModule.uppercase('test')
```

**Summary**

- **[AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition)** – one of the most ancient module systems, initially implemented by the library require.js.
- **[CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS)** – the module system created for Node.js server.
- **[UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)** – one more module system, suggested as a universal one, compatible with **AMD** and CommonJS.

Resources:

- https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_modules-in-javascript
- Wikipedia