# json-stringify-safe , module is not defined error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, json, stringify

I am trying to use [json-stringify-safe](https://github.com/isaacs/json-stringify-safe) in order to prevent `Converting circular structure to JSON` errors that my project is throwing.

Thought that I just need to load `stringify.js` file in my project and that's it, but it gives me this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
>       at stringify.js:1

How do I suppose to use it?

Comment: How did you load this js file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [module.exports "Module is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652716/module-exports-module-is-not-defined)

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to load a nodejs file in a browser. Doesn't work like that.

Comment: i am loading that in asp.net solution `<script src="assets/js/stringify.js"></script> ` It's not the way?