# Azure nodejs Webapp "uncaught referenceerror module is not defined" inside config.js

Tags: node.js, module, azure-web-app-service, require, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Im using a 3rd party system(SFMC) that needs a config.json file or config.js file.
Everything works fine when used config.json

but when I use config.js, im getting Reference error "module is not defined".

Here is my config.js

```
module.exports = {
 workflowApiVersion: 1.1,
 version: 1,
 someVar : process.env.myVar,
 somekey: value
}
```

Trial 2: Also Tried below as suggested here: ([module.exports "Module is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652716/module-exports-module-is-not-defined))

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {  
    module.exports = function configJSON() {
      return {
        workflowApiVersion: 1.1,
        version: 1,
        someVar : process.env.myVar,
        somekey: value
      };    
    };
  });
```

Got this Error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': function configJSON() {
        return {
            workflowApiVersion: 1.1,
            version: 1,
     ...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
```

Trial 3:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    return {
        workflowApiVersion: 1.1,
        version: 1,
        someVar : process.env.myVar,
        somekey: value
      };  
});
```

Got this Error

```
custom.js:251 Could not resolve config.js URL=https://somedomain.azurewebsites.net/config.js
```

And

```
const config = {
 workflowApiVersion: 1.1,
        version: 1,
        someVar : process.env.myVar,
        somekey: value
};
export config;
```

Got this Error:
export is not defined

The file structure is basic as below.

[image]

**Im now switching from JSON to JS since I need to use some env variables. Please let me know what im missing!**

Comment: When declaring a variable inside the `module.exports`, make sure you declare a **_function_** that returns something; otherwise, when you try to import the variable into another module it will be `undefined`

Comment: Yeah trial 3, i do have a function which returns something. But also I used process.env which I think is not getting supported?