# Customizing Intellisense for CommonJS?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am working on an app that targets the atom/electron shell and they use CommonJS in the browser, not AMD/RequireJS.

There is an article on MSDN about [Customizing Intellisense for RequireJS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn904583.aspx) but I cannot find any information about customizing Intellisense for [CommonJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs) (which is the synchronous, Node.js style `require` function). The only CommonJS Intellisense that seems to work in Visual Studio is when editing files in a Node.js project created with [Node Tools for VS](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools).

Is there any other way?

Comment: Agreed this would be a great function. Ironically, the Visual Studio Code editor is smart enough to use the Intellisense on non-node projects.  I suspect we will see this released in visual studio because I imagine they use the same engine.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the new vs15 preview 2 this release includes a Salsa preview. Salsa also powers the JavaScript language service in VS Code.

Salsa: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Salsa-Preview-in-Visual-Studio-15-Preview

vs15 preview: https://msdn.microsoft.com/vs-knownissues/vs15/vs15-preview2-knownissues