# What are the differences between module loading in ES6, AMD, and CommonJS?

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, es6-module-loader

I'd like to learn more about the differences between the following, with special attention to compatibility issues (different browsers, minification, etc), performance, and readability/maintainability.

1. ES6: `export` and `export default` syntax, paired with `import {module1, module2} from`.
2. AMD `define()` syntax.
3. CommonJS `require()` syntax.

Are any more common, in wider adoption? Where will the convention go, and why? What is next for ES6, since it seems to be changing so quickly. Is there a historical reason/motivation for ES6's module loading syntax as-is, and what is next?

Comment: *"Where will the convention go, and why?"* Since modules are part of the language now, every environment has to support this, so I'd go with ES6. *"What is next for ES6, since it seems to be changing so quickly."* The ES6 spec is finished. Any changes are only bug fixes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relation between CommonJS, AMD and RequireJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs)