# Using (NEW) Famo.us Engine with RequireJS and EJS Templates

Tags: express, requirejs, ejs, famo.us, famous-engine

Before Famo.us completely changed their architecture I was developing some Apps using Famo.us, RequireJS, EJS Templates, Node and some other stuff.

But now when I come to replace the old Famo.us architecture with the new Famo.us 'Engine' I am getting errors - which tells me the architecture is wrong for the new approach - so wondered if you guys can help me.

**Background**

- Server is Node.js, Express 4 and some other stuff
- Client will be Famo.us, EJS Templates and some other stuff

The current approach is that the '/' Router calls an 'ejs' template.

index.ejs:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/famous.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <script data-main="/js/webmain.js" src="/js/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This worked fine with old Famo.us architecture...and would call the webmain.js script using RequireJS.

webmain.js:

```
/* globals require */
require.config({
  baseUrl: "js",
  nodeRequire: require,
  paths: {
    "famous": "vendor/famous",
    "famous-flex": "vendor/famous-flex/src",
    json2: "vendor/json2",
    "requirejs": "vendor/requirejs/require",
    "socketcluster": "vendor/socketcluster",
    "ua-parser" : "vendor/ua-parser.min",
    "uuid": "vendor/uuid"
  }
});
require(["platform"]);
```

The 'platform.js' script would contain the following:

```
define('platform', function(require, exports, module) {
  'use strict';
  var Engine = require("famous/core/Engine");
  var contentContext = Engine.createContext();
  var Widget = require('app/widgets/DefaultWidget');
  var mainView = new Widget();
  var contextSize = [undefined, undefined];

  contentContext.setPerspective(1);

  Engine.nextTick(function() {
    contextSize = contentContext.getSize();
    mainView.setOptions({size: [contextSize[0], contextSize[1]]});
    contentContext.add(mainView);
  });
  contentContext.on('resize', function(e) {
    contextSize = contentContext.getSize();
    if (mainView) mainView.setOptions({size: [contextSize[0]*1, contextSize[1]*1]});
  }.bind(this));


});
```

But the new version of Famo.us will not work using this approach and I wanted to ask your thoughts as to why, or if there was another way they have not mentioned?

I have updated the Famou.us source code in 'vendor/famous' to use the 'Famo.us Engine' code from github. If I replace the old Famo.us code in the 'platform.js' script with new Famo.us code - like this:

```
define('platform', function(require, exports, module) {
  'use strict';

var FamousEngine = require('famous/core/FamousEngine');
var DOMElement = require('famous/dom-renderables/DOMElement');

FamousEngine.init();
var scene = FamousEngine.createScene();

var node = scene.addChild();
var domEl = new DOMElement(node, {
    content: 'Hello World',
    properties: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial'
    }
});

});
```

I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "Clock" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) require.js:8
Uncaught Error: Module name "../utilities/CallbackStore" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) require.js:8
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined platform.js:28
```

I guess I am trying to understand, when the RequireJS skeleton is pretty much the same, why it doesn't work?  Why Famo.us is undefined, and why the new Famo.us architecture can break so much - and what the 'new' way of integrating famo.us would be?

I have asked questions on their 'slack' IRC but it doesn't seem to be a way to get answers and a really poor 'help'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am really stuck from moving forward at the moment.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Famo.us version 0.3.5 and earlier used **RequireJS** using [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD).

The new version 0.5.0+ uses the node.js flavor of **CommonJS** and uses [`Browserify`](http://browserify.org/) to build a bundle of your javascript application for the browser.

The following from [an Answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs) sums it up. More about their similarities and differences in the answers.

> **RequireJS** implements the **AMD** API [(source)](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html).
>
> **CommonJS** is a way of defining modules with the help of an `exports` object, that defines the module contents.