# Unable to set JWT header to axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have Django REST as a backend. And I need to query the database over `GET`.
**Problem:**
Header does not in the `GET` method. Therefore Django returns me the 
`"Authentication credentials were not provided."`

**Question:**
Where am I wrong?

```
export function fetchCompanies(token, callback) {
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${ROOT_URL}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'jwt '.concat(token)
    }
    // headers: `{content-type=application/json&authorization='+${jwtReady}}`
    // headers: JSON.stringify(
    //   {'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization': jwtReady}
    // )
  });

  const request = instance.get('/api/companies/')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      callback(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      callback(err.response);
    });
  return{
    type: FETCH_COMPANIES,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

**References:**
https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config

[image: Postman App]

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the right header?

Comment: I add my `Postman` picture to confirm my eyes. And also `Copy&paste` since I have been struggling with this issue for 4 hours by now. My eyes are started to blurred now.

Comment: What are you using in your backend to parse the Authorization header?

Comment: @maxpaj Thank you for your response. I am done with this. The problem comes from backend side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to installed this thing. The problem comes from Backend.
I was misled by be able to get `token` and `POST` to form without `headers`
Which is fine for the login mechanic. By that I though my configuration was right, but actually when @panigrap from `reactjs/redux` gitter channel mentions to me again.

https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Don't know how to fix it correctly, but I've changed code to this:

```
var jwtReady = 'jwt '.concat(token);
...
headers: {'content-type=application/json&authorization='+jwtReady}
```

Also you can try to use

```
JSON.stringify({'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization': 'jwt '.concat(token)}
```

**EDIT:**
Try to write it like this:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'jwt '.concat(token)
}

axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: `${ROOT_URL}/api/companies/`,
  headers: querystring.stringify(headers)
})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    callback(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err.response);
  });
```

Comment: I had tried your attempts. Browser does not shoot out the `request`

Comment: TypeError: name.toUpperCase is not a function
    at processHeader (normalizeHeaderName.js:7)
    at Object.forEach (utils.js:218)
    at normalizeHeaderName (normalizeHeaderName.js:6)
    at transformRequest (defaults.js:32)
    at transform (transformData.js:16)
    at Object.forEach (utils.js:224)
    at transformData (transformData.js:15)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:37)
    at <anonymous>

Comment: @Sarit error occurred in your normalizeHeaderName.js file, at line 7. That's another file.

Comment: I did not made that file. So you are saying dependency is broken?

Comment: @Sarit, Updated my code, please try with `querystring`

Comment: I can not user `require` in Reactjs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623573/what-is-require-function-is-reactjs

Comment: @Sarit, it'd be better if you add react tag to your question.
OK, can you use node-fetch instead of axios?
Or you can try to transform your get request to post with data, instead of headers

Comment: Thank you very much for your response

Answer (score 1):

in my application i'm done this work like below 
first i create a file with name `AxiosConfig.js` and the code is like this, this function read jwt that i stored in local storage and set it on axios config

```
/**
 * this file contains configuration for Axios Library
 */
 import axios from 'axios'

 const AxiosConfig = (config = axios.defaults) =>{
    if(localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')){
    config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')}`
   }
return config;
  }
export default AxiosConfig;
```

now i create another file for calling like this :

```
import axios from "axios";
import axiosConfig from "./AxiosConfig";
 const headers = {};
 class AppsAPI {
 static getAllApps(userId) {
   return axios
    .post("someurl", {}, axiosConfig()) //===> Here i set axios config
  .then(res => res.data)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
export default AppsAPI;
```

Comment: Thank you for your good example. I am done with this. The problem comes from backend side.