# Javascript - how to solve "Uncaught error: undefinedModule"

Tags: javascript, json, arcgis

I'm using a Javascript file to try and get a token from ArcGIS Online. However, whenever I try it, it comes back with

```
init.js:11 Uncaught Error: undefinedModule
```

The file (GetAToken.js) is below:

```
dojo.ready(init);
var request = dojo.require('request'); // npm install request

// generate a token with your client id and client secret
function getToken(callback) {
    request.post({
        url: 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token/',
        json: true,
        form: {
            'f': 'json',
            'client_id': '<<MY_CLIENT_ID>>',
            'client_secret': '<<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>>',
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'expiration': '1440'
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body.access_token);
        callback(body.access_token);
    });
}
```

And the bit which calls it (in a HTML file) is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://esri.github.io/calcite-bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/css/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/"></script>
<script src="GetAToken.js">
    var MyToken = callback(getToken);
    alert(MyToken);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you see a file called `init.js` in your code anywhere? Not 100% the problem, but worth seeing what's in that file..

Comment: Nope. I take it i should try and find out how to add one.

Comment: Not necessarily - in the error message, it's line 11 of that file where the error occurs. If you can find it, that might give a clue as to what module is undefined.

Comment: Don't think I can find it. As I say, there is no `init.js` in my code. Though if I hover over it it lists it as `https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/init.js:11`

Comment: You call and module (with `require`) and the module never loaded before

Comment: Would that indicate that I've got to use a `dojo.require("init");` at the top of the js file? Just quickly tried that and it's still coming back with the same problem.

Comment: seperate the code from the script loading: instead of `<script src="GetAToken.js">
    var MyToken = callback(getToken);
    alert(MyToken);
</script>` write `<script src="GetAToken.js">
</script><script>    var MyToken = callback(getToken);
    alert(MyToken);</script>`

Comment: Sorry, still the same problem.

Comment: @user25730 - Are you trying to run a script in NodeJS server or a IIS/tomcat server?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get the requestJS through NodeJS (`npm install request`). I am right?

You need to be aware that NodeJS require uses CommonJS whereas dojo uses RequireJS. Both of them have different module structures in them. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs)

In the line `var request = dojo.require('request');` It is not able to find `request` module so it is throwing the error.

The way to get nodejs modules in dojo is to use `dojo/node` as show below.

```
require([ "dojo/node!request" ], function(request){
    // Utilise the "request" module
});
```

Go through the Tutorial for [Dojo and Node.js](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/node/index.html)

Hope this was helpful.

PS: Esri has its own request object (`esri/request`), which you can use to get tokens. You may want to use that instead.