# What is CommonJS, AMD, WebPack, Browserify etc.?

Tags: javascript, module, amd, commonjs

I am working with javascript from past 4 years still not aware about below terminologies related to module. Could someone please explain these to me in easy language ?

- AMD
- CommonJS
- ES6
- WebPack
- Browserify

Comment: [Relation between CommonJS, AMD and RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs)

Answer (score 2):

AMD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition

CommonJS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS

ES6: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015

WebPack: https://webpack.github.io/docs/what-is-webpack.html

Broserify: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook

Answer (score 2):

Bad question but...

AMD: http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html

CommonJS: http://www.commonjs.org/

ES6: http://es6-features.org/#Constants

WebPack: https://webpack.js.org/

Broserify: http://browserify.org/