# PouchDB polyfilled for es6 Promises: CommonJS, AMD, RequireJS, ...?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, pouchdb, commonjs

**TL;DR My Question**

To anyone who has successfully used PouchDB and polyfilled es6 (and es5) for older browsers:
How did you do it?

Which *implementation* of CommonJS / AMD / RequireJS was used (if that was the approach)?

Also... did you end up with several `<script>` tags in the index.html file, or all in one?

*Many Thanks*

---

**Background**

I need to use the PouchDB browser database in my web app.

A recommendation at PouchDB.com to deal with a [Common Error](https://pouchdb.com/errors.html) is

> Did you include the [es6-promise shim library](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise)? Not every browser implements ES6 Promises correctly.

The GitHub README of the recommended 'es6-promise shim library' says

> To polyfill the global environment (either in Node or in the browser via CommonJS) use the following code snippet:
> `require('es6-promise').polyfill();`
> Alternatively
> `require('es6-promise/auto');`

Note: "*...or in the browser via CommonJS* "

So, I concluded that I need CommonJS to provide the `require` function.

One issues posted to the es6-promise shim library GitHub page is
[Look for AMD first, then CJS in the UMD #246](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/246) which includes

> ...changes in the es6-promise build since 3.3.0 has introduced a new UMD which checks for a CommonJS env first unlike the old UMD which used to check for an AMD env first.

Which suggests I could use the ("*more suited for the browser*") AMD.

Reading the top answer to [Relation between CommonJS, AMD and RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs):

> - AMD is more suited for the browser, because it supports asynchronous loading of module dependencies.
> - RequireJS is an implementation of AMD, while at the same time trying to keep the spirit of CommonJS (mainly in the module identifiers).

So perhaps `RequireJS`?

Also...

In [Common.js -- A CommonJS preprocessor that builds you CommonJS style app into code the browser can use](http://umbraengineering.github.io/common.js/), it says:

> Step 3: Include the modules into your app and use them

```
<script src="js/common.js"></script>
<script src="js/foo.js"></script>
<script src="js/bar.js"></script>
<script>
    var bar = require('bar');
    bar.doTheThing();
</script>
```

However, [this medium.com article](https://medium.com/@cgcrutch18/commonjs-what-why-and-how-64ed9f31aa46) says:

> Without module systems like CommonJS, dependancies had to be loaded in `<script>` tags in the header of an HTML file, OR all code had to be lumped together which is incredibly slow and inefficient for file loading.

These seem to conflict.

---

**Note**

Polyfilling es5 *seems* to have been very straightforward:
Simply include `<script src="./es5-shim-master/es5-shim.min.js"></script>` in the index.html file.  The browser doesn't complain.