# Have a startup script to NodeJS CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

How do you add a startup script to the `node.js` cli? E.g. for `require`ing modules or setting some options?

EDIT:
I'm talking about the *server* side, i.e. I want to be able to start up the `node` CLI at any part of my system and have it preload a startup script (similiar to a `bashrc`) on a global level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript require() on client side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168451/javascript-require-on-client-side)

Comment: You're probably going to have to emulate your own repl using the [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) API. Soon I'll be home, and I'll write up a basic prototype if you don't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read your post, I realized that the current Node.js REPL sucks! So I made a basic demo of the functionality of your post, and I called it [rattle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rattle).

Here, I'll explain each line of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

This is the shebang, it makes sure that it's run as Node

```
const repl    = require("repl"),
      vm      = require("vm"),
      fs      = require("fs"),
      path    = require("path"),
      spawn   = require("child_process").spawn,
      package = require("./package");
```

Import all the packages, you know the drill

```
function insertFile(file, context) {
  fs.readFile(file, function(err, contents) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    vm.runInContext(contents, context);
  });
}
```

I defined function to insert a file into a VM context (which the REPL is)

```
if (process.argv.includes("--global")) {
  console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, ".noderc"));
```

Display the location of the global .noderc

```
/** Hijack the REPL, if asked **/
 } else if (process.argv.length < 3 || process.argv.includes("-i") || process.argv.includes("--interactive")) {
```

This starts to be the meat of the code. This detects if the user wants to enter REPL mode

```
  console.log(`rattle v${package.version}`);

  var cmdline = repl.start("> "),
      context = cmdline.context;
```

Create the repl, with the standard prompt, and get the VM Context

```
  /** Insert config files **/
  fs.access(localrc = path.resolve(process.cwd(), ".noderc"), function(noLocal) {
    if (!noLocal) {
      insertFile(localrc, context);
    }
  });
```

Test if there's a local .noderc, if there is insert it into the context

```
  fs.access(globalrc = path.resolve(__dirname, ".noderc"), function(noGlobal) {
    if (!noGlobal && globalrc !== localrc) {
      insertFile(globalrc, context);

    }
  });
```

Test for global .noderc, and insert it

```
} else {
  /** Defer to node.js **/

  var node = spawn("node", process.argv.slice(2));

  node.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

  node.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
}
```

The rest of this just passes the code to node, because it's not REPL stuff

This was fun to write, and hopefully useful to someone.

Good Luck!